# Override Ctrl+M hotkey of Facebook in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, firefox, jquery-plugins

I'm working on a [**bookmarklet**](http://torifat.github.com/jsAvroPhonetic/) which will let users to write on any input fields in our language. We choose `Ctrl+M` for switching layout between default and our language (Inspired by Wikipedia). It was working fine in almost every website with chrome. When we started checking with **Firefox** we found that it only fails in **Facebook**.

> Moreover, Facebook catches the `Ctrl+M` from outside the `window`
>   scope. Like, form the address bar, search bar, firebug console, etc.

I've tried with raw javascript, jQuery and also with the [jQuery Hotkeys](https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys) plugin by [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) but no luck :(

Here is a version that I had tried. You can run it on your Firebug console for testing purpose -

```
(function(){
    var noConflictMode = false;
    if(typeof $ !== 'undefined') noConflictMode = true;
    if(typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
        var root = (document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]);
        var ns = document.createElementNS && document.documentElement.namespaceURI;
        var script = ns ? document.createElementNS(ns, 'script') : document.createElement('script');
        script.type = 'text/javascript';
        script.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (this.readyState == 'complete') test();
        }
        script.onload= test;
        script.src= 'https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.min.js';
        root.appendChild(script);
    } else {
        test();
    }

    function test() {
        if(noConflictMode) jQuery.noConflict();
        jQuery(window).on('keydown keyup keypress', function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            // For Firefox
            e.stopPropagation();
            // Extra effort :|
            e.stopImmediatePropagation()
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            console.log(e);
            return false;
        });
    }

})();
```

Comment: Unrelated to the `Ctrl+M` thing, but what if the page in question already has jQuery loaded and *doesn't* want `noConflict` mode? Your `test` function will muck up the page.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Nice Point, I had fixed it in my original code (https://github.com/torifat/jsAvroPhonetic/blob/master/dist/avro-bookmarklet-1.1-beta.js#L16). For sake of simplicity I had deleted it form here.

Comment: The first argument for `.delegate()` is a selector.  Did you mean `.bind()`?

Comment: @gilly3 Yes sorry, I wrote `bind` inside `live` in my original code. When converting I forgot about the `delegate` params. Thanks, Again I'm fixing :)

Comment: What Ctrl+M does in facebook? It doesn't seem to work for me

Comment: @Darhazer did you tried it on Firefox? It opens the new message window. (Firefox only problem)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can NOT do that on client-side web for security reasons, you can code anything in JS or JQ or any language you want but MOZ never will take care of your code.

Take care, one thing is that the browser "compile" your code and work with it, and another thing is that you can change the browser itself. For that reasons there's the "add-on".
For example, you can't change the kernel of Visual Studio programming in V.S. :D

BUT...

... you can ask to the user re-bind the keys, you have 3 ways to do that:

1) installing a MOZ add-on (or your own addon)

2) Working with: http://mxr.mozilla.org/seamonkey/source/dom/public/idl/events/nsIDOMKeyEvent.idl

3)  installing a shortcut keyb at OS level with higher priority than the App (in this case, MOZ) (you can do it with C#). Alt+tab combination is an example of high level shortcut, or "Prnt Scrn"

There is NO way to do that with about:config, neither.

Maybe this url can help you, but i suggest you try asking for changes in MOZ and not asking for Javascript code.

http://www-archive.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#keys

Comment: And that's the way because Firefox is more secure than IE and Chrome lol

Comment: Think that Firefox is not Chrome, so it's not a google app. It's based on Netscape and their people has not a real profit for it.
I mean, so, think about (i dont really know but it's 99% probably) that in his kernel has very specific work just for facebook functions (like it has it for google, g+, gmaps, etc). I suggest you comment this on a very specific firefox's community here in StackOverflow or outside. More aside MOZ than Jquery, Javascript or Facebook issue

Comment: That also came into my mind that they internally did that. I did a rigorous search for that. But, Didn't find any clue. BTW, thanks for your effort, I up voted you :) But, sorry can't accept your answer because It doesn't cover what I wanted.

Comment: No problem, but I still think that you need a work-around, I made some addons for firefox and from i know, i think there is no answer for this question, at least as you want :)